Is there a way of creating multiple stratified samples at once?
Let say I have this input dataset with the Ids: a, b, c
I need to order it by packages of +-100 rows each sample with the same distribution of Ids as the input entire population.
What would be the best way to do that?


You can take StratifiedShuffleSplit which is used to splits your dataset into two portions data_train and data_test. And both are stratified based on vector y.
For your problem you can specify size/number of rows in test and then take generated test dataset.

# pip install scikit-learn
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
import numpy as np


# dataset
X = np.random.random(size = [1000, 2]) 

# your 'ids/groups' for stratification
y = np.random.randint(10, size=(X.shape[0],)) 

# n_splits - number of different sample datasets to create
# test_size - number of rows required in sampled dataset
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=500, test_size=100, random_state=0)


# iterate through generations.
# stratifications will be done based on `y`
for _, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    print (test_index.shape)
    X_sampled = X[test_index]

